# Добавление значения в с таблицу MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, база-данных

Есть значение ( 777 x 777 ), мне нужно добавить его в таблицу базы данных (id, width, height).
Как это сделать с помощью Javascript ?

Comment: хе-хе, а разве можно? Или W8 и не такое привнесла? )

Насколько знаю, JS такими средствами не располагает.Через JS можно отправить запрос на добавление какому-нибудь скрипту (на php/python/c# etc), а уже этот скрипт и выполняет добавление.

UPD: почитайте ответы [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020751/can-javascript-connect-with-mysql). Там приведено несколько решений (которые все-таки через посторонний скрипт работают). Может быть, что-то вас и устроит (или хотя бы подтолкнет в нужном направлении)

Comment: Вообщем значения screen.width и screen.height заносились в таблицу бд

Comment: Наверное, тут уже php нужно?

Comment: а воообще)))) идея - сделать статистику разрешений экрана посетителей которые заходят на сайт

Comment: Не обязательно PHP, любой другой серверный язык подойдет, можете даже на плюсах что-нить написать )))

Я выше комментарий обновил, там на SO ссылка. Может быть какие-то решения вам больше понравятся (например node.js или meteor), сам с ними не работал, подсказать по ним ничего не смогу.

Хотя с PHP работать новичку проще будет.